# запись данных в 1 столбец из 1 переменной pandas python

Tags: pandas

Пишу парсер, у меня в цикле идет парсинг города с разных страниц, и все лежит в одной переменной, если я в цикле пишу код на запись данных этой переменной в xlsx, то каждый раз файл перезаписывается, а мне надо, чтобы он записывал каждое значение в столбик
[image]

Вот как показано на скриншоте, а он мне просто перезаписывает значение переменной снова и снова, не добавляя повторно, помогите пожалуйста буду очень рад!
[image: Вот мой код]

Comment: А где ваш код? Без кода непонятно как помогать

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11mbqcf  Вот мой код)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Тут есть человек, который может помочь в данном вопросе? что не понятно? в цикле моем идет перезапись файла, а я хочу, чтобы каждый раз была запись в столбец Город!!!

Comment: Копите location в список и потом делайте df на основе этого списка

Comment: Не совсем понял, можно кодом?